# Power BI column chart showing incorrect counts

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, data-modeling

I'm creating a simple column chart simply by dragging and dropping. This is a single table, no relationships with other tables whatsoever.

Data is as follows-

[image: Data with two columns Date1 and Date 2 as Date formatted as MMMM yyyy format.]

I'm dragging and dropping these columns and I'm getting the following view -

[image: Weirdly Date2 has one count in July which doesn't exist in data. Not sure why this is happening?]

The chart axis as as follows -

[image: Axis]

Can anyone help me I've searched all over the internet and it seems like a peculiar issue I'm facing.

Thank you.

Expect the July count to show up in september.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try creating a new Measure with:

```
Date2 Count = 
  var minD = MIN('Table'[Date1])
  var maxD = MAX('Table'[Date1])
  RETURN 
    CALCULATE(
      COUNT('Table'[Date2]),
      ALLSELECTED('Table'),
      minD <= 'Table'[Date2] && 'Table'[Date2] <= maxD
    )
```

Then use this measure in your chart instead of "Count of Date2".

Comment: Hey! Thanks, Sam. I appreciate the help. Can you explain what went wrong and why restricting it to min and max of Date1 is working? Also, won't this fail if Date2 is higher than Date1 so that count won't probably reflect?

Comment: You are using Date1 as your dimension for the chart. So for Sept, min & max will be Sept 1 and Sept 30. Then we are saying how many in Date2 are in this range. Nothing really went wrong with what you had, as it was merely counting for Date1 if it has a value (any value) in Date2.

Comment: Thank you for that amazing and simple explanation. I have the following doubt if I'm applying a filter it's pretty much applying for only Date1 (which means it's showing correct data for Date1 probably because it is Dimension for the chart) if I had to show the correct filtered data a.k.a it applies independently to both Date1 and Date 2 then how should I go about it?

Comment: Sorry, not following/understanding, if you have a date filter, count for both Date1 and Date2?

Comment: Yes. Currently, what is happening for example I have a filter for the state California selected then the count for September for Date1 is correct but the count for Date2 is fixed to 3 for September no matter what state I'm selecting if September shows up Date2 will always have a fixed count of 3 but Date1 will be correct.

Comment: Oh I see, then replace `ALL('Table')` with `ALLSELECTED('Table')` - I've updated the answer above with the same.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256233/discussion-between-aman-yadav-and-sam-nseir).